# Mule:Appending lines in a file for a mule based messaging system

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Is there a way to append line using file outbound connector of mule in existing file ?.  Having this requirement of processing millions of message and append a new line of data in a file for each message. What is the most optimized approach to achieve this using file outbound in Mule.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to append lines to an already existing file, you can set the 'outputAppend' attribute to true.

```
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true"
    outputAppend="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true"
    doc:name="File" />
```

Furthermore you can use the batch module to to process millions of messages. For more information check: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing

Answer (score 1):

What Clare said about `outputAppend="true"` is right, but please take into account that when you use it the maximum amount of active dispatchers goes down to 1, which could seriously impact performance.
On the other hand, I assume what you want is to take a file and just add some content at the end, so you'll need a File input source. In this case what you can do is configure a "Work directory" in your file connector, and use the same directory as the output path for the file outbound endpoint.
This way, the file is taken and moved by the file inbound endpoint, and then taken by the file outbound endpoint to add the payload at the end.
As a result, the file content is never consumed and you just add the configured payload at the end of the file.

Here an example configuration:

```
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="false" outputAppend="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true"/>
<flow name="appendPayloadToFile">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/source-dir/" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" />
    <set-payload value="ADDED-CONTENT"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/target-dir/" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000"/>
</flow>
```

If this solution is not performant enough, you could try creating a custom java component that takes the file from the inbound endpoint, closes it, open it again for output and append the required content.

If you have some flow to work with please share it.

HTH,
Marcos